# select{outline:none} disabled others styling of SELECT element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, outline

I have many SELECT elements on a page, the problem is that in IE11 they have an outline which I try to remove it using CSS : 
select{outline:none;}

It works fine as long as , it is the only style element! As soon as I add more style e.g background-color to SELECT, the outline:none does not work anymore!

It should work in **IE** and for **SELECT** element. However in other browser, there is no outline applied to element by default.

thanks in advance

[image: IE11 vs other browsers]

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the select element border:none;

Answer (score 0):

By using a bit CSS you can get same style across all browser.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kiwufihe/2/edit)**.

```
select{
  outline:none; 
  border:1px solid #E4E4E4; 
  padding:10px; 
  width:200px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
}
```

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your reply. After you  wrote me this I tried to change "X-UA-Compatible" and now it works properly with out applying anychanges in style :)

I put the following line in <head>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />